# resolve.modules per entry point

Tags: webpack

I have a project that uses multiple entry points to create a few distinct apps. The directory structure looks something like:

```
.
├── app-1
│   └── components
│       ├── a.js
│       └── b.js
├── app-2
│   └── components
├── app-3
│   └── components
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

Within any of the apps, I would like to be able to import files without referencing the app name. For example, in `app-1/components/a.js` I would like to be able to import `b.js` with

`import B from 'components/b'`

and have webpack know that this is referring to `app-1` because that's where the file lives, and not, say, `app-3` in case the same path exists there.

With the following setup in `webpack.config.js`:

```
...

resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app-3'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app-2'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'app-1'),
    'node_modules',
  ],
}

...
```

`app-3` will have the highest priority. What I would really like is to have no priority, but instead search for a module based on the app it lives in.

Not sure if I'm explaining this properly, but I've scoured the web for a solution and can't find one. Would love for someone to come along with a easy fix and a snarky "do you even google"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin could help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-entry-modules-webpack-plugin.

It does exactly what you want, add the entry to the resolution path while keeping distinct entries not importing from each other.

Comment: This does appear to do exactly what I was looking for. Ended up going with another solution at the time (for other reasons), but I'll have to try out this plugin in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and resolved it with aliases. My imports are looking now:

`import "@app1/components/b"`

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: Is there a way to cut out the `app1` part and have it be `import components/b`? Afaik aliases can't achieve that behavior.